# Sort order of each select statement in a mysql union

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some trouble with the sort order of my selects in my union statement. I want to sort each select like firs for the name and second for the id.

```
(SELECT
  id,
  name
FROM
  table1
WHERE
  active=1
ORDER BY name)
UNION
(SELECT
   id,
   name
FROM
   table2
WHERE
   active=1
ORDER BY id)
```

Everything work fine without the where clause, but this is necessary for my query. How can i do different sorts for each select?

table1:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | First |
| 3 | Second |
| 2 | Third |

table2:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | First1 |
| 2 | Second1 |
| 3 | Third1 |

result table1+table2:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | First |
| 3 | Second |
| 2 | Third |
| 1 | First1 |
| 2 | Second1 |
| 3 | Third1 |

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Comment: You must use UNION ALL. *Everything work fine without the where clause* No. This is combined dataset sorting effect (which needs for duplicates detection/removing which UNION DISTINCT must provide).

Comment: That should work - granted, the sample data you've given is already in order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select id,name from 
(
Select * from (
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.name,
  @rownum := @rownum + 1 as row_number
FROM
  test t
 cross join (select @rownum := 0) r
WHERE
  t.active=1
 order by t.name  ) tbl1

union all

select * from 
(
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.name,
  @rownum := @rownum + 1 as row_number
FROM
  test2 t
 cross join (select @rownum := 0) r
WHERE
  t.active=1
 order by t.id 
  ) tbl2
  ) x order by row_number
```

you should use `union all`

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dzBHKuzGmaQC8EmyuWcH2Y/2